# Shall I use “the” before “sound” and also “smell” ( the sound and the smell or the sound and smell ? )

Tags: grammaticality, conjunction-reduction, writing-advice

> I adore the sound and [the] smell of the rain falling at a late quiet night.

When should I keep the second “the” in the sentence?

Comment: Hello and welcome to EL&U. Stack Exchange prefers that questions are focused, so I’ve edited out the parts of your question that aren’t related to the issue stated in the title. I’ve also expressed the question explicitly in the question text. Questions here are also expected to include information about what you’ve checked so far - this helps the community to avoid going over things you already know, and helps us focus on what you want to know.

Comment: Regarding the other queries in your original question post - feel free to post each one as a separate question, accompanied in each case by some information about what you’ve found so far and what you’re still interested to find out about that topic.

Answer (score 0):

You would use *the sound and smell* to refer to the combination, but *the sound and the smell* to refer to them separately, for example if like the sound and you like the smell even when they are not together.

The phrase "at a late quiet night" is odd. "Late at night" is standard, but "quiet" doesn't fit into it well. Perhaps "late on a quiet night" or "late at night when it is quiet" would work.